# Asp.net core installed on existing IIS 10 ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: iis, .net-core

I want to try something out but I'm nervous b/c we only have a single production server and no dev server. So I always tread carefully when doing anything on it. It's a strange place to work when they won't give me a dev server to test code out on before going to production...

Using IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016 running an asp.net MVC 4 app, I'd like to install ASP.NET Core for IIS to test out running a new rest api. But I don't want to install ASP.NET Core and find out that it did something to IIS that broke the existing mvc 4 app already running in production. I understand that the Dotnet Core runs behind IIS, so it shouldn't touch the IIS runtime, but with Windows there is always the chance that something got changed during installation and now the existing site stops working, and I'm scrambling to figure out how to fix it.

Can someone give me their experience with trying this? Would installing asp.net core on a Windows 2016 server impact an existing asp.net mvc 4 app?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: "I understand that the Dotnet Core runs behind IIS, so it shouldn't touch the IIS runtime" is incorrect. As you have to install ASP.NET Core module on IIS, the impact is always there. You don't need a production Windows Server in many cases, as Windows 10 is usually enough.

Comment: @LexLi You're forgetting that you can also run ASP.NET Core behind IIS (using AAR, FastCGI, etc) as opposed to running it *inside* IIS (using that ASP.NET Core IIS module). I believe you can also "install" the module by having the binaries in your Website's Application scope so it doesn't alter the server-wide configuration.

Comment: and then there's also IIS Express, "IIS Hostable Web Core", and running Kestrel with HTTP.SYS directly.

Comment: @Dai if you check Microsoft's guides, none of those alternatives is talked about in details. "I believe you can also "install" the module by having the binaries in your Website's Application scope so it doesn't alter the server-wide configuration." But that's not what people get from the default installation, so if that breaks IIS (rarely, but happened in the past) people won't be able to fix that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net MVC use ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 and asp.net handler aspNetCore handler. If you need to test asp.net core in your IIS then you only have to install asp.net core web hosting bundle. Only install asp.net core shouldn't corrupt an exisiting site.

If your MVC4 site get corrupted, then must be something wrong with your deployment method.

If you need to host asp.net core and mvc application under same IIS. Please ensure they are under different sub-applications so that MVC and .net core application won't corrupt each other.